# How to remove this vertical line in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

[image: look here]

hide the Vertical line, for clear

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your question? That is not enough information.

Comment: my english is very poor.sorry. I just want to hide the left vertical line.keep the editor clear.

Comment: Still not clear on "vertical line". Can yoy please post "normal" screenshot with arrows pointing to the line. Your current one did not made it clear (at least for me)

Comment: look this plz: http://p1.bqimg.com/567571/4e5cd704cee27ca6.png

Comment: If you want to remove "part #2" .. then @avilac is correct -- that's a space for VCS markers (added/modified/deleted lines). To remove it you will need to disable VCS integration for this project (git .. or whatever you have got there) as I do not know another way of hiding them.

Comment: now I see.thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any kind of repository in this project?

Because git usually marks deleted lines like this (with red border), new lines with green and modified ones with blue, if I don't remember bad.

If so, check if the repository is in sync with the content of the file and checkout it in case it's not.

Hope it helps!